# Why can I boot from a USB device without "making it bootable"?

Tags: boot, usb, bios, uefi, mbr

It seems like you can boot from a USB device without a bootloader to me. 
Even my 6 years old computers that still have a BIOS.

From what I read the BIOS simply looks for an mbr, loads it and executes it. 
But I have never knowingly written an mbr to any of my USB devices. So how is it that I can still boot from them when certain files are present? 
I doubt that the mbr could be inside of a file, because how would you ensure that it is exactly at the beginning of the partition.

So what am I missing?

Comment: The device is bootable because it was made bootable at some point.  It could have been done by you as part of another process.  It's impossible to answer without knowing what the devices were, what was on them when you got them, and what you did to them and how you did it.

Comment: I usually format my USB devices before copying files onto it for booting. So unless Windows itself is interfering in the process, there should not be an mbr or anything on it. The devices were standard USB thubdrives. Most of them are USB 2, some are USB 3.

Comment: Who are the people voting to close this question?! It's a damn good question! @Forivin Formatting does *not* touch the MBR. Use the `diskpart` command-line tool in Windows to erase MBR + partition information using the `clean` command. TIP: remove drive letter/mount points first. http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/52129-disk-clean-clean-all-diskpart-command.html

Comment: @misha256, the question isn't how to accomplish it, the question is how did it get accomplished when the OP doesn't remember doing it.  There are all kinds of ways it could have ended up bootable, and the OP hasn't provided any information that would allow readers to do more than speculate.

Comment: @misha256 I don't currently have a USB device handy that I could try this on. But as soon as I tried it, I will come back and report if it still booted or not.

Comment: @fixer1234 Actually OP changed his question. In the previous version he said "I formatted the USB key" and I needed to highlight the fact that that formatting does not touch the MBR. Also, the `diskpart` advice will allow OP to prove for himself that clearing the MBR renders the USB key not-bootable. *Then* he can try figure out how the key got bootable in the first place. My comments are intended to help OP investigate for himself what's going on. If I actually had a real answer to the question, I would have posted it as an answer not a comment :-)

Comment: My question was never edited.